# Javascript Loop for show/hide DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 6 DIVs that show and hide, triggered by an onClick event. Currently if you click the 6 different pictures that trigger these divs, they all show up on top of eachother.

I would like only one DIV to show up at a time. So when you click a different image, it hides the currently displayed div and shows the new one.

I am guessing I need to loop through these somehow, can anyone point me in the right direction? My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".slidingDiv").hide();
            $(".show_hide").show();
            $('.show_hide').click(function () {
                $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
            });

            $(".slidingDiv2").hide();
            $(".show_hide2").show();
            $('.show_hide2').click(function () {
                $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
            });

            $(".slidingDiv3").hide();
            $(".show_hide3").show();
            $('.show_hide3').click(function () {
                $(".slidingDiv3").slideToggle();
            });

            $(".slidingDiv4").hide();
            $(".show_hide4").show();
            $('.show_hide4').click(function () {
                $(".slidingDiv4").slideToggle();
            });

            $(".slidingDiv5").hide();
            $(".show_hide5").show();
            $('.show_hide5').click(function () {
                $(".slidingDiv5").slideToggle();
            });

            $(".slidingDiv6").hide();
            $(".show_hide6").show();
            $('.show_hide6').click(function () {
                $(".slidingDiv6").slideToggle();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML and CSS, or better yet a jsFiddle?

Comment: As implied, the *best* answers require us to see the HTML and (ideally) see it in action, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/); your current code looks like you're solving the problem of repetitive mark-up by adding more classes, rather than using a clean approach.

Comment: It is a VERY bad idea to set the initial state of a elements display with Javascript. These elements should be hidden with css by default then shown with js.

Comment: @rlemon: unless the user's disabled JavaScript (I know, I know: a mythical beast..!), which then prevents  *anyone* from seeing the content. If you're going to *show* with JavaScript, *hide* with JavaScript.

Comment: If the user has disabled JS and your site requires JS to be usable there should be an appropriate `<noscript>` message (kinda like how SO does, however it looks like the message is delivered from the server?) Otherwise if it is state driven the user could submit the request to the server and the server could respond with a page including the specific markup you wish to show. (my 2 cents)

Comment: @DavidThomas @relmon always depends on what is required. hiding elements within the `ready` event is bad because it could be visible for a short time. it's true that hiding it with css only is also not always suitable (SEO or disabled js), `noscript` is only visible if script js is disabled. often the following technique is usefull: add `js` to the `class` of `<html>` (can be accessed before `ready`) via javascript, and then using a css rule like `.js .hidden-with-js  {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure if this is what you're going for, but something like this might work:

**HTML:**

```
<img class="div1" src=...>
<img class="div2" src=...>
<img class="div3" src=...>
<!-- more images can go here -->

<div class="div1">text1</div>
<div class="div2">text2</div>
<div class="div3">text3</div>
<!-- more divs to display go here -->
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("img").click(function () {
    $("div").slideUp(190);                      // hide divs previously shown
    var divSelect = $(this).attr('class');      // get class of div to show
    $("div."+divSelect).delay(200).slideDown(); // show div after other slides up
});
```

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bStnv/)

Answer (score 0):

I am still working on simplifying it, but it works. You will have to repeat it to every div, giving different selector names. When I figure a loop out, I will let you know.

Good luck!

```
<!--HTML starts-->              

<div class="med-wrap-video">
    <div> <p class="body-text"> <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6z9KMHt-Ta4" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
      <br>
        <a href="#" class=".a selector">Read More</a></p>

     <br>
        <span class="selector1">

          <p class="body-text">
            Title: <br>
            Composer: <br>
            Year: <br>
         </p>
       </span>

  </div>    
</div>

<!--JS begins-->    

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".selector1").hide();        

$(".a selector").click(function(event){    
 event.preventDefault();           //prevents page to reload
$(".selector1").slideToggle(600);
      $(this).toggleClass(".selector1");
    });
```